# Small OutlinedButton is not aligned to start

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

My goal is to implement a tiny outlined icon button:

[image: Requirement]

However, `OutlinedButton` is giving me a headache, when the size goes below a certain level, the button starts to stop aligning to the left, akin to having `startMargin`.

[image: Compose Preview]

The question is, how can I align my small button to the start? Appreciate in advance for any helps!

Below is my code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ButtonPreview() {
  SetelTheme {
    Surface(
      color = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.3f),
      modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
      Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
      ) {
        OutlinedButton(
          onClick = {},
          border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
          shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
          contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
          modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .defaultMinSize(
              minWidth = 24.dp,
              minHeight = 24.dp,
            ),
        ) {
          Text("1")
        }

        OutlinedButton(
          onClick = {},
          border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
          shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
          contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
          modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
        ) {
          Text("big is ok")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's tricky because `OutlinedButton` internally uses `Button` component which uses `Surface` component and there is `.minimumInteractiveComponentSize()` modifier in it which applies minimum width and height to `OutlinedButton`. You need to create custom button component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hint: You can create `CustomButton` component like this and modify content color and container color according to your need or you can pass them as arguments:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ButtonPreview() {
    Surface(
        color = Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.3f),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        ) {
            CustomOutlinedButton(
                onClick = {},
                border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize()
                    .defaultMinSize(
                        minWidth = 24.dp,
                        minHeight = 24.dp,
                    ),
            ) {
                Text("1")
            }

            OutlinedButton(
                onClick = {},
                border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
            ) {
                Text("big is ok")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
@Composable
fun CustomOutlinedButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    shape: Shape = ButtonDefaults.outlinedShape,
    border: BorderStroke? = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonBorder,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) =
    CustomButton(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = modifier,
        enabled = enabled,
        shape = shape,
        border = border,
        contentPadding = contentPadding,
        content = content
    )
```

```
@Composable
fun CustomButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    shape: Shape = ButtonDefaults.shape,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val containerColor = if (enabled) Color.Blue else Color.Gray
    val contentColor = if (enabled) Color.White else Color.White.copy(0.4f)
    val shadowElevation = 0.dp
    val tonalElevation = 0.dp

    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .semantics { role = Role.Button }
            .clickable {
                if (enabled) {
                    onClick()
                }
            },
        shape = shape,
        color = containerColor,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        tonalElevation = tonalElevation,
        shadowElevation = shadowElevation,
        border = border
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides contentColor) {
            ProvideTextStyle(value = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .padding(contentPadding),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    content = content
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! couldn't trace myself earlier. you are right! It all boils down to this special Surface constructor that comes with the onClick param which there is a non-nego `.minimumInteractiveComponentSize()` modifier appended